# The component doesn't display correctly with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm learning java swing and this is very confused to me. The quit button doesn't display. However, if I move the code part of `textArea` after the two parts of buttons, it will display correctly. So why?

```java
package exercise1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ChatClient {
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton btnSend;
    private JButton btnQuit;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    private void launchFrame() {
        panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 50);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 3;
        panel.add(scrollPane, c);

        btnSend = new JButton("Send");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        panel.add(btnSend, c);

        btnQuit = new JButton("Quit");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        panel.add(btnQuit, c);


    }

    protected ChatClient() {
        frame = new JFrame("Chat Room");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        launchFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be using a gridHeight of 3. You only have buttons on two rows, so trying to specify a component to fill 3 rows won't work. It won't cause a problem, but the "intent" of your code is misleading. The gridHeight should be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: You forgot to reset `c.gridheight = 1;` after adding the JScrollPane. Without doing this, the send button will overlie the quit button.

```
private void launchFrame() {
    panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;  // ** This is also worthwhile **

    textArea = new JTextArea(10, 50);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridheight = 3;
    panel.add(scrollPane, c);

    btnSend = new JButton("Send");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridheight = 1;  // ********* ADD THIS *********
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    panel.add(btnSend, c);

    btnQuit = new JButton("Quit");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    panel.add(btnQuit, c);

}
```